# how to send email from localhost using codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

```js
    function sendMail() {

  $config = Array(
  'protocol' => 'smtp',
  'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',
  'smtp_port' => 465,
  'smtp_user' => 'xxx@gmail.com', 
  'smtp_pass' => 'xxx', 
  'mailtype' => 'html',
  'charset' => 'iso-8859-1',
  'wordwrap' => TRUE
);

        $message = 'test';
        $this->load->library('email', $config);
      $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
      $this->email->from('xxx@gmail.com');
      $this->email->to('xyz@gmail.com');
      $this->email->subject('testing');
      $this->email->message($message);
      if($this->email->send())
     {
      echo 'Email sent.';    
     }
     else
    {
     show_error($this->email->print_debugger());  
    }

}
```

> This is my code, i am trying to send email from localhost using codeigniter , i got message "Email sent." but i didnt got any mail in gmail account.

Comment: Have you check email in junk mail???

Comment: Make sure you set up you mail settings in you localhost if you are using windows with wamp or xampp here is a video tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TO7MfDcM-Ho

Comment: Did you setup email server ?

Comment: you should allow lesssecureapps to be able to login to your email then using smtp server try this https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps

Comment: is it works?? or still error running??

Answer (score 4):

```
 $config = Array(
'protocol' => 'smtp',
'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',
'smtp_port' => 465,
'smtp_user' => 'xxx@gmail.com',// your mail name
'smtp_pass' => '*****',
'mailtype'  => 'html', 
'charset'   => 'iso-8859-1',
 'wordwrap' => TRUE
);
```

then

```
$this->load->library('email', $config);
```

### **Mail Settings in XAMPP(Impotent)**

```
$this->email->from('mygmail@gmail.com', 'myname');//your mail address and name
$this->email->to('target@gmail.com'); //receiver mail

$this->email->subject('testing');
$this->email->message($message);

$this->email->send(); //sending mail
```

Configuration in **sendmail.ini**

path   `c:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.ini`

Configurations

```
[sendmail]

smtp_server=smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port=25
error_logfile=error.log
debug_logfile=debug.log
auth_username=myemail@gmail.com
auth_password=yourgmailpassword
force_sender=myemail@gmail.com
```

in **php.ini**

path`c:\xampp\xampp\php\php.ini`

```
[mail function]
sendmail_path = "\"C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe\" -t"
```

Comment: I have found the article which demonstrate how to send emails in a CodeIgniter application using SMTP. https://www.cloudways.com/blog/send-email-codeigniter-smtp/

Answer (score 0):

I see you are missing `$this->email->initialize($config);` Also make sure you have set up your email settings on you localhost else will not work.

Also `$config = Array(` change to `$config = array(`

Replace Google Mail "gmail"

`'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com'`

With

`'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com'`

Code

```
function send_mail() {

$config = array(
  'protocol' => 'smtp',
  'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com',
  'smtp_port' => 465,
  'smtp_user' => 'xxx@gmail.com', 
  'smtp_pass' => 'xxx', 
  'mailtype' => 'html',
  'charset' => 'iso-8859-1',
  'wordwrap' => TRUE
);


$this->load->library('email', $config);

$this->email->initialize($config); // Add 

$this->email->from('xxx@gmail.com');
$this->email->to('xyz@gmail.com');
$this->email->subject('testing');

$message = 'test';
$this->email->message($message);

if($this->email->send()) {
  echo 'Email sent.';    
} else {
  print_r($this->email->print_debugger());  
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Email Cannot be sent locally you should. This method can be test on test server..

Comment: This should be comment not answer.

Comment: Sir i mention the answer above

Comment: Combine both answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $CI =& get_instance();
    $CI->load->library('email');
    $CI->email->initialize(get_email_config());

    $CI->email->from($data['email_from'],WEBSITE_TITLE); // Constant is define which exist email
    $CI->email->to($data['email_to']);
    if(isset($data['bcc']) && !empty($data['bcc'])){
        $CI->email->bcc($data['bcc']);
    }else{
        $CI->email->bcc('other_email');
    }
    if(isset($data['upload'])&& !empty($data['upload'])){
        $CI->email->attach($data['upload']);
    }
    $CI->email->subject($data['subject']);
    $CI->email->message($data['body']);
    $CI->email->send(TRUE);
```

Comment: This will allow you the email send in BCC too and also will share the attachment.