# Php send mail() is not working

Tags: php, email

I am using free hosting [of this link](http://000webhost.com) and i tried to user php send `mail()` but it does not work.. here is my code:

```
<?php
      if(mail('example@yahoo.com','from mail','your subscription is almost over, you need to renew', 'sample header')){
          echo 'mail sent';
      }else{echo 'not sent';}
?>
```

I tried also using this in `localhost` and edited my SMTP in php.ini. Is there any way in sending mail in php that will work also in free hosting?

Comment: your free host has no SMTP Server so you have to use another server to send mai lfrom

Comment: Try removing the ", 'sample header'". It does not follow the header format. "From: sample header"

Comment: Remove `header` parameter and send again. `sample header` is not the actual parameter.

Comment: noticed the red X next to SMTP Server? it means you have to pay for it, in order to use SMTP.

Comment: i tried it removing 'sample header' but still not working.. if it is not free hosting will it work?

Answer (score 0):

```
// mail(to,subject,message,headers,parameters);
$to = 'example@yahoo.com';
$subject = 'Subscription Information';
$message = 'your subscription is almost over, you need to renew';
$headers = "From: info@mydomain.com" . "\r\n" .
            "CC: you_too@mydomain.com";

$mail =mail($to,$subject,$message, $headers);

if(isset($mail))
{
    echo 'mail sent';
}
else
{
    echo 'not sent';
}
```

[image]

[PHP `mail()` Function](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mail_mail.asp)

Comment: this one is echoing 'mail sent' but i don't receive any in my email inbox or spam..

Comment: what are the things that i have to change in my php.ini?

Comment: i checked it out already. will this work in localhost as the server? i am using xampp with php ver. 4.4.14

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30610387/cant-send-email-with-php-mail-function-on-windows-8/30610643#30610643