# Not receiving mail sent by mail() function in php

Tags: php, email, xampp

The below code shows "Message sent successfully..." but mail sent out doesn't receives in inbox or spam folder of receiver.

```
<?php
    $to = "rcvr@example.com";
    $subject = "This is subject";

    $message = "<b>This is HTML message.</b>";
    $message .= "<h1>This is headline.</h1>";

    $header = "From:mymailid@gmail.com \r\n";
    $retval = mail ($to,$subject,$message,$header);
    if( $retval == true )
    {
    echo "Message sent successfully...";
    }
    else
    {
    echo "Message could not be sent...";
    }
?>
```

I've changed [mail function] in php.ini as like this

```
[mail function]
SMTP = smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port = 587
sendmail_from = mymailid@gmail.com
sendmail_path = "\"C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe\" -t"
```

And [sendmail] in sendmail.ini like this

```
smtp_server=smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port=587
smtp_ssl=tls
error_logfile=error.log
pop3_server=
pop3_username=
pop3_password=
force_recipient=
hostname=

auth_username=mymailid@gmail.com
auth_password=mymailid_pass
force_sender=mymailid@gmail.com
```

So everything is fine and `$retval` returns true and echo 'Message sent successfully...' but receiver don't get it at his inbox or in spam.
I also enabled `imap` in gmail `settings->forwarding and pop/imap`.

Comment: was your gmail configured properly ? Send a test mail from your other account (yahoo etc) and check whether you are receiving any mails ?

Comment: Did you check the error.log file?

Comment: @Priya - how can I check  error.log file where it is?

Comment: Give a path instead of trying this error_logfile=error.log in sendmail.ini and check the log file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
    $to = "rcvr@example.com";
    $subject = "This is subject";

    $message = "<b>This is HTML message.</b>";
    $message .= "<h1>This is headline.</h1>";

    $header = "From:mymailid@gmail.com \r\n";
    $retval = mail($to,$subject,$message,$header);
    if(isset($retval))//change
    {
        echo "Message sent successfully...";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Message could not be sent...";
    }
?>
```

and **comment the below line in `php.ini`**

```
sendmail_path="C:\xampp\mailtodisk\mailtodisk.exe"
```

[Read this answer to Config Your localserver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30610643/4595675)

Comment: in my `php.ini` line `sendmail_path="C:\xampp\mailtodisk\mailtodisk.exe"` not present only `sendmail_path = "\"C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe\" -t"` present and I comment this line but still not working

Comment: not that line. there is another line. Search it once

Comment: No. I searched but there is only `sendmail_path = "\"C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe\" -t"` line present