# How to send an email with php code?

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

I was trying to send an email from within my codeigniter project, and the command         `echo $this->email->print_debugger();` kept returning the following:

> 220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP q139sm4099547wmd.2 - gsmtp
>   hello: 250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [41.228.226.174] 
>   250-SIZE 35882577
>   250-8BITMIME 
>   250-STARTTLS 
>   250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES 
>   250-PIPELINING 
>   250 SMTPUTF8 
>   Failed to send AUTH LOGIN command. Error: 530 5.7.0 Must
>   issue a STARTTLS command first. q139sm4099547wmd.2 - gsmtp  Unable to
>   send email using PHP SMTP. Your server might not be configured to send
>   mail using this method.

so I went back and tried to send email with a simple php code without codeigniter and turns out that the initial problem had nothing to do with codeingiter since I failed again.
here is my php code:

```
<?php
$to       = '**********@gmail.com';
$subject  = 'Testing sendmail.exe';
$message  = 'Hi, you just received an email using sendmail!';
$headers  = 'From: ******@gmail.com' . "\r\n" .
            'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n" .
            'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8';
if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers))
    echo "Email sent";
else
    echo "Email sending failed";
?>
```

and here is the mail configuration in php.ini and for the record, I tried the following function with the lines `smtp_port = 25` and `sendmail_from = ********@gmail.com` commented (with the initial ";") and without the ";" because I read that suggestion in a forum while trying to solve my problem.

```
[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/smtp
SMTP = smtp.gmail.com
; http://php.net/smtp-port
smtp_port = 25

; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/sendmail-from
;sendmail_from = ********@gmail.com

; For Unix only.  You may supply arguments as well (default: "sendmail -t -i").
; http://php.net/sendmail-path
sendmail_path="C:\wamp\sendmail\sendmail.exe -t -i"
```

I also tried removing the line `sendmail_path=.....`

and finally here is my sendmail.ini:

```
; configuration for fake sendmail

; if this file doesn't exist, sendmail.exe will look for the settings in
; the registry, under HKLM\Software\Sendmail

[sendmail]

; you must change mail.mydomain.com to your smtp server,
; or to IIS's "pickup" directory.  (generally C:\Inetpub\mailroot\Pickup)
; emails delivered via IIS's pickup directory cause sendmail to
; run quicker, but you won't get error messages back to the calling
; application.

smtp_server=smtp.gmail.com

; smtp port (normally 25)

smtp_port=25

; SMTPS (SSL) support
;   auto = use SSL for port 465, otherwise try to use TLS
;   ssl  = alway use SSL
;   tls  = always use TLS
;   none = never try to use SSL

smtp_ssl=

; the default domain for this server will be read from the registry
; this will be appended to email addresses when one isn't provided
; if you want to override the value in the registry, uncomment and modify

default_domain=

; log smtp errors to error.log (defaults to same directory as sendmail.exe)
; uncomment to enable logging

error_logfile=error.log

; create debug log as debug.log (defaults to same directory as sendmail.exe)
; uncomment to enable debugging

debug_logfile=debug.log

; if your smtp server requires authentication, modify the following two lines

auth_username=***********@gmail.com
auth_password=*******************

; if your smtp server uses pop3 before smtp authentication, modify the 
; following three lines.  do not enable unless it is required.

pop3_server=
pop3_username=
pop3_password=

; force the sender to always be the following email address
; this will only affect the "MAIL FROM" command, it won't modify 
; the "From: " header of the message content

force_sender=************@gmail.com

; force the sender to always be the following email address
; this will only affect the "RCTP TO" command, it won't modify 
; the "To: " header of the message content

force_recipient=

; sendmail will use your hostname and your default_domain in the ehlo/helo
; smtp greeting.  you can manually set the ehlo/helo name if required

hostname=localhost
```

Any help would be highly appreciated since I have spent over 3 days trying to solve this problem to no avail.

edit: the second code indeed returns "Email sent" but I can't find it anywhere not even in the spam. and yes I have configured gmail to" allow less secure apps"

Comment: In Local or live server

Comment: I'm afraid that didn't solve the issue

Answer (score 0):

Your E-Mail sending part is correct. No issue with it.

If you are sending mail through you have to configure email settings correctly.

1. If **XAMPP** [Read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30610387/cant-send-email-with-php-mail-function-on-windows-8/30610643#30610643)
2. If **Wamp** [Read This](http://yogeshchaugule.com/blog/2013/configure-sendmail-wamp)

> **Note:** If you have live server, upload it to live. Its easy to check than configure local settings and all.

Comment: upload it to live server

Answer (score 0):

Your email code is ok, but if you are using wamp server .....need to change these following things...

1. Access your email account. Click the Gear Tool > Settings >
   Forwarding and POP/IMAP > IMAP access. Click "Enable IMAP", then
   save your changes
2. Run your WAMP Server. Enable ssl_module under Apache Module.
3. Next, enable php_openssl and php_sockets under PHP.
4. ** set **sendmail_path** both **php.ini** file on `"C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12\php.ini"` and
   `"C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.9\bin\php.ini"` **

> sendmail_path = "C:\wamp\sendmail\sendmail.exe -t"

8. Restart Wamp Server.

I think it will be worked.

Answer (score 0):

in config/email.php , i had to add

$config['smtp_crypto']  = "tls";