# Steps to correctly create form to sending emails in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

I'm trying recently to write a form for sending emails in codeigniter and it shows a problem with sending.

> Failed to authenticate password. Error: 535-5.7.8 Username and Password not >accepted. Learn more at 535 5.7.8 https://support.google.com/mail/answer/14257 >2sm864121lja.37 - gsmtp 
>   Unable to send email using PHP SMTP. Your server might not be configured to >send mail using this method.

I'm using the same password as to gmail account. In php.ini I set:

```
sendmail_path = "\"E:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe\" -t"
```

instead

```
;sendmail_path = "\"E:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe\" -t"
```

and in sendmail.ini I set up a auth_username, auth_password, smtp_port and smtp_server.

it is my view(myform.php):

```
<?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
<?php $this->load->helper("form");
echo form_open('form'); ?>
<h5>Tytul</h5>
<input type="text" name="topic" value="<?php echo set_value('topic'); ?>"     
size="50" />
<h5>Text</h5>
<input type="text" name="text" value="<?php echo set_value('text'); ?>" 
size="50" />
<h5>Nick</h5>
<input type="text" name="username" value="<?php echo set_value('username'); 
?>" size="50" />
<h5>Email Address</h5>
<input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo set_value('email'); ?>" 
size="50" />
<div><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></div>
</form> <?php echo $this->session->flashdata('msg'); ?>
```

It is my controller (form.php):

```
<?php
class Form extends CI_Controller
{
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->helper(array('form','url'));
    $this->load->library(array('session', 'form_validation', 'email'));
}

function index()
{
    //set validation rules
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'username', 'required|min_length[5]|max_length[12]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Emaid ID', 'required|valid_email');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('text', 'text', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('topic', 'topic', 'required');

    //run validation on form input
    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
    {
        //validation fails
        $this->load->view('myform');
    }
    else
    {
        //get the form data
        $name = $this->input->post('username');
        $from_email = $this->input->post('email');
        $subject = $this->input->post('topic');
        $message = $this->input->post('text');

        //set to_email id to which you want to receive mails
        $to_email = 'email@gmail.com';

        //configure email settings
        $config['protocol'] = 'smtp';
        $config['smtp_host'] = 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com';
        $config['smtp_port'] = '465';
        $config['smtp_user'] = 'email@gmail.com';
        $config['smtp_pass'] = 'password';
        $config['mailtype'] = 'html';
        $config['charset'] = 'iso-8859-1';
        $config['wordwrap'] = TRUE;
        $config['newline'] = "\r\n"; //use double quotes
        //$this->load->library('email', $config);
        $this->email->initialize($config);                        

        //send mail
        $this->email->from($from_email, $name);
        $this->email->to($to_email);
        $this->email->subject($subject);
        $this->email->message($message);
        if ($this->email->send())
        {
            // mail sent
            $this->session->set_flashdata('msg','<div class="alert alert-success text-center">Your mail has been sent successfully!</div>');
            redirect('form/index');
        }
        else
        {

            //error
          echo $this->email->print_debugger();
        }
    }
}


}
?>
```

Comment: Trying in local host ??

Comment: yees, I forget to write about it. Sorry

Comment: Check your local settings. Or upload it to live server and check. if you dont have domain try free hosting

Comment: I changed local settings which are recomend. Ok i try free hosting

Comment: When i add this line:
     $config['mailpath'] = '/usr/sbin/sendmail';
i have new error
>Exit status code: 1
>Unable to open a socket to Sendmail. Please check settings.
>Unable to send email using PHP Sendmail. Your server might not be >configured to send mail using this method.
>This is a multi-part message in MIME format.
>Your email application may not support this format.

Comment: in live host?? or local??

Comment: This error shows in localhost after add this one line. In live host I have problem with importing so it will take my more time

Comment: XAMPP, old version may cause this problem ? I try to upgrade my xampp

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30610387/cant-send-email-with-php-mail-function-on-windows-8/30610643#30610643

Comment: I changed php.ini and sendmail.ini too. No changes

Comment: @Mrfet did you find any solution to this ??I am having the same problem