# Php mail() not working, output of the code is success but I do not receive any emails

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, server, sendmail

I use `mail()` to send emails but the output says it is success but i do not received any emails. can someone help me please in using `mail()`?

```
function send_mail() {

    $message = 'Please reset your passwrod etc.';

    if (mail('ruedastefano@gmail.com', 'password reset', $message, 'from: bjmpncr@thefourpobu.com')) {

        echo 'success';
    } else {
        echo 'failed';
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any error?

Comment: View your /var/log/mail.log

Comment: do you send correct headers etc? Else try some php mail library

Comment: Code looks fine. Just to confirm, where you are executing? On your local environment or on Server?

Comment: Gmail may be refusing your e-mail as a result of (spam)filters. The best way to test if your script is working is to send it to an emailaddress other than Gmail. When it does, read about 'SPF' records to ensure your email is not marked as spam.

Comment: Have you thought about using codeigniter email helper http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/email_helper.html since you have codeigniter tag.

Comment: Please have print_r(error_get_last()); after your code so you can catch up the error. It might be something related to your mail server misconfiguration. Or mails are just delayed few minutes.

Comment: Please check how to remove captcha or reset captcha from your email account. It has generated some problem while you send email from your email server.

Answer (score 0):

Its because your mail config not set correctly.

Check

1. Environment(if local [check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30610387/cant-send-email-with-php-mail-function-on-windows-8/30610643#30610643) / if live-host most of time it will config automaticaly)
2. User Authentication(Username / password)

---

**Sample code**

```
$to = "abdulla@stackoverflow.com";

$subject = 'Place Order From ';
$message = 'My message goes here';

$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
$headers .= "From: ibjmpncr@thefourpobu.com";

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

---

**Requirements for php `mail()` function**

[**php.net**](http://php.net/manual/en/mail.requirements.php#mail.requirements)

For the Mail functions to be available, PHP must have access to the sendmail binary on your system during compile time. If you use another mail program, such as qmail or postfix, be sure to use the appropriate sendmail wrappers that come with them. PHP will first look for sendmail in your PATH, and then in the following: /usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/etc:/etc:/usr/ucblib:/usr/lib. It's highly recommended to have sendmail available from your PATH. Also, the user that compiled PHP must have permission to access the sendmail binary.

[**w3Schools**](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ref_mail.asp)

For the mail functions to be available, PHP requires an installed and working email system. The program to be used is defined by the configuration settings in the php.ini file.

Comment: this is live host. where can I find the php.ini?

Comment: Check with service provider

Comment: Read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24644436/php-mail-form-doesnt-complete-sending-e-mail

Comment: There is no php.ini file in my hosting. Also where do I get this file, where to put and what is the content inside of it?

Comment: @TepTep Ya there are no ini file. Contact your service provider and get mail information.  Check wheather its sendmail or not

Comment: @TepTep any update on this ?? If solved please accept it

Comment: not yet. I try to send mail in other hostings it works. When I look the phpinfo the mail.add_x_header is off while on other hosting it is on

Comment: @TepTep request your host provider. they have to setup it fro you