# Send Mail Using CI Email Libraries

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

```
    $this->load->library('email');

    $this->email->from($_POST['email'], $_POST['name']);
    $this->email->to(CONTACT_US_MAIL1);

    $this->email->subject($_POST['subject']);
    $this->email->message($_POST['message']);

    $this->email->send();
```

Error while sending mail from CI

```
mail(): Failed to connect to mailserver at "localhost" port 25, verify your "SMTP" and "smtp_port" setting in php.ini or use ini_set()
```

Comment: Read this too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30610387/cant-send-email-with-php-mail-function-on-windows-8/30610643#30610643

Comment: Cannot see any of your email http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/email.html#setting-email-preferences