# Sending email from localhost using xampp to gmail with Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

Im trying to send an email from my localhost using xampp to Gmail with Codeigniter.

This is my code in the controller:

```
public function mail()
{
    $config = Array(
        'protocol' => 'smtp',
        'smtp_host' => 'smtp.gmail.com',
        'smtp_port' => 465,
        'smtp_user' => 'kingkangddg@gmail.com',
        'smtp_pass' => '*****',
        'new_line' => "\r\n",
        );

    $this->load->library('email', $config);
    $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");

    $this->email->from('kingkangddg@gmail.com', 'Glenn Samporna');
    $this->email->to('fajardokarlelbert@gmail.com');
    $this->email->subject('Test');
    $this->email->message('sample message');

    if($this->email->send()){
        echo 'sent';
    } else {
        show_error($this->email->print_debugger());
    }

}
```

It throws out errors like this:

```
hello: F

The following SMTP error was encountered: F
Unable to send email using PHP SMTP. Your server might not be configured to send mail using this method.

Date: Mon, 29 Jan 2018 09:35:37 +0100
From: "King Kang" <kingkangddg@gmail.com>
Return-Path: <kingkangddg@gmail.com>
To: fajardokarlelbert@gmail.com
Subject: =?UTF-8?Q?Test?=
Reply-To: <kingkangddg@gmail.com>
User-Agent: CodeIgniter
X-Sender: kingkangddg@gmail.com
X-Mailer: CodeIgniter
X-Priority: 3 (Normal)
Message-ID: <5a6edcd99171d@gmail.com>
Mime-Version: 1.0


Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

sample message
```

**A PHP Error was encountered**

> Severity: Notice
>   Message: fwrite(): send of 6 bytes failed with errno=10053 An
>   established connection was aborted by the software in your host
>   machine.
>   Filename: libraries/Email.php
>   Line Number: 2242
>   Backtrace:

I hope you can help me out with this one.

Comment: any update on answer ??

Answer (score 0):

Tested and worked fine on my local.

**Changes**

1. Removed `new_line`
2. Port changed.
3. SMTP Encryption added. (4th argument)

**[Check My answer to another question how to configure mail setting in xampp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30610387/cant-send-email-with-php-mail-function-on-windows-8/30610643#30610643)**
Check the php.ini for this path is there

```
sendmail_path   /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i    /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i
```

---

**Code**

```
$config = Array(
    'protocol' => 'smtp',
    'smtp_host' => 'smtp.gmail.com',
    'smtp_port' => 587,
    'smtp_crypto' => 'tls',
    'smtp_user' => 'kingkangddg@gmail.com',
    'smtp_pass' => '*****',
);
```

---

**Make sure:** Two-way authentication turn offed and third-party access allowed