# php mail not sending Why?

Tags: php, email

i have a folder name php contains file name index.html on my desktop and i have install xampp in my C://xampp folder .Plz tell me how to structure php folder
index.html contains this code. But this code not sending email .is there any problem in my folder structure php

```
<!Doctype html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>My email Page</title>
</head>
 <body>
  <div>
   <?php
     $email = "example@yahoo.com";
     $subject = "hope this works";
     $body = "i think all is well";
     $header = "from Ali@yahoo.com";
     mail($email , $subject, $body $header);
     echo "ok all well";
   ?>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: double check ur mail()

Comment: You have to learn the difference between html and php. It is _not_ the same and php has to be handled specially by your http server. Please search for some basic introduction to php on the internet. Ther are plenty and it makes zero sense to copy all that here.

Comment: Have you set up php.ini file. if not, go through with <http://www.quackit.com/php/tutorial/php_mail_configuration.cfm>

Comment: `mail($email , $subject, $body $header);` it's a typo.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get your xampp run your php script first. So change your `index.html` to `index.php`. When you visit your page from browser via `http://localhost/php/index.php`, you can see if that php snippet runs or not.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running on localhost such as XAMPP, then chances are the PHP mail function won't work as you do not have a mail service running, hence no mail will be sent. See [Why mail() PHP function does not work with WAMP default installation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3412055/why-mail-php-function-does-not-work-with-wamp-default-installation)